# Create Meteor Account based on Oauth token and Service (Facebook, Google, etc)

Tags: oauth, meteor

Is there an easy method call one can do to create a user on Meteor using an oauth token provided by a registered service such as Facebook or Google? Intuition says that such a method should exist, where it automatically pulls in details about the user, and adds it to the services field. However, I've poked around the codebase, and am so far unable to find this method.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: To clarify, I don't want to use the built in Oauth flow, but my own flow - but still end up with a user account the same way as the built in system.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the user accounts created by the Google and Facebook auth packages?

Comment: The current flow uses pop-ups, and there are currently problems associated with pop-ups, especially on mobile devices. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/8B1kjjvRimE

Comment: You can hack the current flow to display the popup contents as a normal, expanded page element. It's fairly easy.

Comment: @HubertOG Could you elaborate on what you mean by "normal, expanded page element." Is there any example I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

Try `meteor add accounts-base accounts-google accounts-facebook accounts-ui`. Those packages will do most of the work for you, and then you just need to add the `{{loginButtons}} to your template, and fill in your API information when the easy form asks you to.

EDIT: to roll your own, you might want to check out Arunoda's post on [extending Meteor accounts](http://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html), or maybe a [community-contributed oauth package](https://github.com/vladikoff/meteor-accounts-persona) for inspiration.

Comment: Sorry, didn't communicate my question clearly enough now that I read it again. I meant without using the built in oauth flow. Basically - can I make my own Oauth flow, but then use existing methods to take a token and generate a user?